# Ruby string gsub captures invalidated if using them

Tags: ruby, regex, string, gsub

There's a typical piece of `gsub` code here:

```
str = '[caption id="attachment_3655" align="aligncenter" width="1024"]<a href="http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sample-image.jpg"><img class="size-large wp-image-3655" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/sample-image-1024x768.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" /></a> Image title[/caption]'

p str.gsub(/\[caption.*?\]<a href=\"(.+?)\".*?><img .*?\/><\/a>(.+?)\[\/caption\]/) { |match|
  href = $1.sub("http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/", "")
  title = $2

  "#{href} - #{title}"
}
```

After this call `$1.sub("http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/", "")` capture data `$2` becomes `nil`. If I first access `$2` above it works. Why calling `sub()` invalidates captures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why calling `sub()` invalidates captures?

For the same reason why calling `gsub` **sets** them. That's a side-effect of these methods, they set these pseudo-global variables.

From reading the documentation, you might get an impression that these variables are set only in the block form. This is not so.

```
'foobar'.sub(/(foo)/, 'bar') # => "barbar"
$1 # => "foo"
```

And since your `sub` pattern does not contain match groups (and it isn't even a regex), capture pseudo-globals are cleared, naturally.

```
'foobar'.sub('foo', 'bar') # => "barbar"
$1 # => nil
```